# React TypeError: this.state.descriptions.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fix this error
[image]

What I'm trying to do is to render an automated form which is built by this function:

```
let descriptionsForm = (
        <form>
        {this.state.descriptions.map((description, index) => (
            <Input
                key={index}
                elementType={description.elementType}
                elemenyConfig={description.elementConfig}
                value={description.value}
                invalid={!description.valid}
                shouldValidate={description.validation}
                touched={description.touched}
                changed={(event) => this.descriptionInputChangedHandler(event, index)}
                />
        ))}
        </form>
    )
```

It works when first time opening the page, but when I tried to type something in that Input tab, the error shows up.

Here's the descriptionInputChangedHandler function:

```
descriptionInputChangedHandler = (event, index) => {
    console.log("ORIGINAL: ", this.state.descriptions)
    const updatedDescriptions = {
        ...this.state.descriptions
    };

    const updatedDescriptionElement = {
        ...updatedDescriptions[index]
    };
    updatedDescriptionElement.value = event.target.value;
    updatedDescriptionElement.valid = this.checkValidity(updatedDescriptionElement.value, updatedDescriptionElement.validation);
    updatedDescriptionElement.touched = true;
    updatedDescriptions[index] = updatedDescriptionElement;

    let formIsValid = true;
    for (let index in updatedDescriptions) {
        formIsValid = updatedDescriptions[index].valid && formIsValid;
    }
    console.log("UPDATED D: ", updatedDescriptions);

    this.setState({descriptions: updatedDescriptions, descriptionFormIsValid: formIsValid})
}
```

the console.log()s looks like this, which I assume should be correct

[image]

I imagine since the input slot was rendered properly when launching, should be something happened when updating the data, which I have no idea of.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORIGINAL is an array, UPDATED D is an object.

```
    const updatedDescriptions = {
       ...this.state.descriptions
    };
```

should be:

```
    const updatedDescriptions = [
       ...this.state.descriptions
    ];
```

Comment: what is your suggested solution?

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Did you figure that out by the first line of the console logs having a "0" key or not?

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing that caught my attention. Also the ORIGINAL was [...] whereas the other one was {...}.